# How can I make an android application unremovable?

Tags: android

How can I make an android application non-removable? No one can uninstall it from Application Manager.

Comment: Unless you feel like hacking the OS, I don't think this is possible (seems like it'd be a huge security flaw if it was possible).

Comment: Why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: dont install it. then noone will be able to uninstall.

Comment: The device should be rooted and the user give admin privileges to your application. Ans also, why would you do such a thing?

Comment: are you making a nagware app? Who would want to use an app that you cant' get rid of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to make the application a System Application.

You cannot do this unless you have a rooted device and third party software or as others have stated, the app came preinstalled on the phone.

Answer (score 4):

Unless it's a system app that is pre-installed with the ROM on the phone, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Its only possible when the device is rooted. 
Many applications are saying: you need root to run this - maybe you could do this too.

Comment: If the device is rooted, it's also just as easy to remove the app as you normally would :-)

Comment: There your right!
But at least you can make it "official" unremovable ;)